# sh via Ruby: Running ulimit and a program in the same line

Tags: ruby, sh, ulimit

I am trying to run some computational-intense program from Ruby via the following command:

```
%x(heavy_program)
```

However, I sometimes want to limit the running time of the program. So I tried doing

```
%x(ulimit -St #{max_time} & heavy_program)
```

But it seems to fail; the "&" trick does not work even when I try it in a running sh shell outside Ruby.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use either `&&` or `;`:

```
%x(ulimit -St #{max_time} && heavy_program)

%x(ulimit -St #{max_time}; heavy_program)
```

However using `ulimit` may be not what you really need, consider this code:

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout(max_time){ %x'heavy_program' }
```

`ulimit` limits **CPU time**, and `timeout` limits total running time, as we, humans, usually count it.

so, for example, if you run `sleep 999999` shell command with `ulimit -St 5` - it will run not for 5 seconds, but for all 999999 because `sleep` uses negligible amount of **CPU time**

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the difference between "&", "&&" and ";" in this context?

Comment: `&` means run specified task in background, and it will not likely work from ruby's `%x`; `cmdA && cmdB` means "run cmdB ONLY IF cmdA succeed"; `cmdA; cmdB` means "run cmdA first, then cmdB"